# React event.target.value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I was wondering if I could add a method in my component so I could click the `h1` element to redirect to the respective `target.value` page by inserting an `onClick` event like the code below:

```
import React from 'react'
import CollectionItem from '../collection-item/collection-item.component'
import './collection-preview.styles.scss'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


const CollectionPreview = ({ title, items, history }) => (
    <div className='collection-preview'>
        <h1 className='title' onClick={(event) => history.push(`/shop/${event.target.value}`)}>
            {title.toUpperCase()}
        </h1>
        <div className='preview'>
            {
                items
                    .filter((item, index) => index < 4)
                    .map((item) => (
                        <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />))
            }
        </div>
    </div>
)

export default withRouter(CollectionPreview)
```

But it didnt work. The `event.target.value`  always return `undefined`, even though when i tried to console log only the `event.target` , it normally return the `h1` element  I was clicking. How could I fix this?

Comment: @uhamad Hafiz what your event is having?

Comment: Only form control elements have a `value` property. Regular DOM elements do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to understand why you use a onClick event on a H1. I think you use a Link instead inside your H1 tag.

```js
import React from "react";
import CollectionItem from "../collection-item/collection-item.component";
import "./collection-preview.styles.scss";
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const CollectionPreview = ({ title, items, history }) => (
  <div className="collection-preview">
  
    <h1 className="title">
      // You should use a Link component instead on the onClick props
      <Link to={`/shop/${title.toUpperCase()}`}>{title.toUpperCase()}</Link>
    </h1>
    
    <div className="preview">
      {items
        .filter((item, index) => index < 4)
        .map(item => (
          <CollectionItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default withRouter(CollectionPreview);
```

Hope it helps.
Happy coding

Comment: Ok actually, I'm kinda felt ashamed for not thinking about `Link`. Thank you so much for the solution @jbergeron :)

Comment: No worry @MuhamadHafiz, we all do this little mistakes :) Keep coding

Answer (score 0):

If it's listing page and wanna navigate to particular page of listing.

```
<h1 className='title' onClick={() => history.push(`/shop/${title}`)}>
    {title.toUpperCase()}
</h1>
```

instead of

```
<h1 className='title' onClick={(event) => history.push(`/shop/${event.target.value}`)}>
    {title.toUpperCase()}
</h1>
```